# eslint / babel-eslint issue with escope

Tags: babeljs, eslint

Currently getting this error when i try to run eslint locally:

```sh
Error: Cannot find module 'escope'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
    at monkeypatch (/Users/pablorincon/Documents/SSENSE/micro-services/ws-website/services/ui-website/node_modules/babel-eslint/index.js:53:26)
    at Object.exports.parse (/Users/pablorincon/Documents/SSENSE/micro-services/ws-website/services/ui-website/node_modules/babel-eslint/index.js:358:5)
    at parse (/Users/pablorincon/Documents/SSENSE/micro-services/ws-website/services/ui-website/node_modules/eslint/lib/linter.js:671:23)
    at Linter.verify (/Users/pablorincon/Documents/SSENSE/micro-services/ws-website/services/ui-website/node_modules/eslint/lib/linter.js:806:27)
    at processText (/Users/pablorincon/Documents/SSENSE/micro-services/ws-website/services/ui-website/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine.js:278:31)
    at processFile (/Users/pablorincon/Documents/SSENSE/micro-services/ws-website/services/ui-website/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine.js:320:18)
    at executeOnFile (/Users/pablorincon/Documents/SSENSE/micro-services/ws-website/services/ui-website/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine.js:655:25)
    at fileList.forEach.fileInfo (/Users/pablorincon/Documents/SSENSE/micro-services/ws-website/services/ui-website/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine.js:693:13)
    at Array.forEach (native)
```

What's weird is that im using the **same** linting configuration with another project, and i had no issues at all.

I'm using:
babel-eslint@7.1.1
eslint@4.0.0-beta.0

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though I had same package.json, babel-eslint was set as "7.1.1" in one and "^7.1.1" in the other.

Basically ESLint v4 uses a new fork of escope, which was then updated on version 7.2.3 of babel-eslint.

So, adding the little ^ to my configuration fixed my problem.